# Proper way to getDescendants() on THREE.js as of r68

Tags: javascript, three.js

Since [r68](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r68), the `getDescendants()` method has been removed from `THREE.Object3D`.

What's the recommended way to perform the same function now? (since no warning message was provided...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `getDescendants()` method that was removed from r.68:

```
THREE.Object3D.prototype.getDescendants = function ( array ) {

    if ( array === undefined ) array = [];

    Array.prototype.push.apply( array, this.children );

    for ( var i = 0, l = this.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

        this.children[ i ].getDescendants( array );

    }

    return array;

};
```

If you want to write something custom, you can use the `Object3D.traverse()` method;

```
object.traverse( function( node ) {

    // your code here

} );
```

three.js r.68

Comment: Thank you. I ended up implementing my own `getDescendants()` method which does the same as the original one. I was wondering why it was taken out...

Comment: Internally, the library no longer needed it, and I guess the hope was that you wouldn't either. : - )